# How to get `\enquote` command to work when nested inside `\uline` command?

Tags: csquotes, quoting, ulem

When writing `\uline{\enquote{test}}`, the result is typeset but a square is added and LaTeX throws an error

> Package csquotes Error: Unbalanced groups or invalid nesting.
> \uline{\enquote{test}}

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}
    
    \uline{\enquote{test}}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `lua-ul` package instead of `ulem` (requires compiling with lualatex)

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{document}
    
    \underLine{test \enquote{test} test}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]